# Run an exe after another in parallel

Tags: python, linux, parallel-processing

I want to run four .exes in parallel. After the first iteration of the first .exe the second .exe must start while the firts keeps on its second iteration, and so on with the others. The goal is the four in parallel feedbacking each other with data. The exes are written in Fortran 90, but the code is in linux python.

```
import os, threading

e = range(10)
for a in e:
    def exe1():
        os.system("./exe1")

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=exe1, args=())
    t1.start()
    t1.join()

    if a > 0:
        for b in e:
            def exe2():
                os.system("./exe2")
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=exe2, args=())
        t2.start()
        t2.join()

        if b > 0:
            for c in e
                def exe3():
                    os.system("./exe3")        

            t3 = threading.Thread(target=exe3, args=())
            t3.start()
            t3.join()

            if c > 0:
                for d in e
                    def exe4():
                    os.system("./exe4")
                t4 = threading.Thread(target=exe4, args=())
                t4.start()
                t4.join()
```

This is my idea but i don't have the capacity to run them in parallel. They must do 10 iterations each.

Comment: if you `join` as soon as you `start` your threads, no wonder why it doesn't run in parallel.

Comment: and what's the loop with only a function definition in there? that's sick!

Comment: Take a look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess) module. It may be better suited for what you are doing.

Comment: I don't think parallel means what you think it means, my friend.

Comment: your indentation is really off. Almost made me miss the point.

Comment: Your title makes *no* sense. It basically says, "run executable sequentially in parallel."

Answer (score 1):

I won't comment further on the loops defining functions (very weird) probably because the indentation is really off, so there may be more that 4 threads in parallel (I figured out that much).

But to answer your question, your x executables don't run in parallel just because you're using `join()` on the thread as soon as you start it.

So main program waits for current thread termination before it tries to start another.

I would do this:

```
thread_list = []
```

at the start of your program.

Each time you create a thread, store its reference in `thread_list`:

```
t1 = Threading.thread(...)
thread_list.append(t1)
```

Then, remove all the `join` calls inside your program. Now you're really starting x processes within x threads, in parallel.

And at the end of your program wait for all threads to finish:

```
for t in thread_list:
    t.join()
```